# How can I test a program which publishes to Websphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a program which publishes data to IBM Websphere MQ via the MQAX200 interface. I'm struggling to work out how to test it.

What's the simplest way of setting up an application to consume the messages from the queue and confirm they're correct? I don't currently have any MQ infrastructure here (that's on the client's site).

Do I need a message broker? Are there any open source implementations? Or do i need to purchase Websphere MQ, in which case what's the minimal license I'd require?

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 4):

As your application is written using a MQ interface, you need MQ to test. If it's just for testing, you can use the [trial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wmq/) version of MQ.

As far as I know MQAX200 interface supports only P2P messaging and not Publish/Subscribe messaging. So using your application put message to a queue and then use the application like `amqsget`to receive message.

You don't need message broker.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to clarify what it is you are trying to do.  If you are publishing messages then your test program will need to subscribe.  If you are putting messages into a queue then your test program will need to GET messages from the same queue.

The [WMQ Trial Download](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wmq/) will get you a 90-day WMQ license for no charge.  The trial code includes the server and the client libraries so you can set up a QMgr and then test your program in client or bindings mode, as appropriate.  If you elect to install the sample code you also get compiled binaries with which you can test.  For example, `amqsget` gets messages and `amqssub` subscribes to topics, both using bindings mode (shared memory).  The client versions of these (`amqsgetc` and `amqssubc`) attach over the network.  If you are using topics, make sure to subscribe *before* you publish.  If using queues, make sure to `GET` *after* you `PUT`.

Other useful programs include `amqsgbr` to browse messages on queues and `amqsbcg` which will hex-dump the messages and parse the message headers.  Also, WMQ Explorer comes with the Windows and Linux versions of the trial and you can use that to browse, subscribe or get messages.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a simple Java JMS program that subscribes to the Topic. THen you only need to install the free WebSphere MQ Client.

[This article](http://hursleyonwmq.wordpress.com/2007/05/29/simplest-sample-applications-using-websphere-mq-jms/) is a bit old but should do.